# Let $f(z)=\frac{z+1-i}{z-1+i}$ be a map. What is the image of $f(S)$ where $S=\{z\in \mathbb C | im z>rez\}$

Tags: conformal-geometry

> Let $$f(z)=\frac{z+1-i}{z-1+i}$$ and $S=\{z\in \mathbb C | im z>rez\}$.What is the image of $f(S)$?

I sketched the region, and it corresponds to a halfplane, from $\pi/4$ to $5\pi /4$. I tried mappning individual points such as $f(i)=(1-2i)/5$, $f(-1)=(2i-1)/5$ to see the pattern, but unable to see it.

I know that the map should preserve angles, but my set is infinite, and I don't know how to parametrize it.

Comment: The image is obviously bounded. So, you only have to consider the image of the boundary $\{x+ix : x\in\mathbb R\}$. Consider especially the absolute values of the elements of that image.

Comment: Möbius Transformations are the keyword here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $f$ in the form
$$ f(z)=\frac{z-(i-1)}{z-(1-i)} $$

The set $S$ is the half-plane of points closer to $i-1$ than to $1-i$, hence $f(S)$ is the open unit disk.

Comment: I see that $i-1$ actually lies inside $S$ while $1-i$ is outside $S$. But I don't see why $f(S)$ would be a unit disk. I do see that it's less than $1$. I tried multiplying the denominator by the conjugate without success.

Comment: $|f(z)|$ is less than one for each $z\in S$, because the absolute value of the numerator is equal to the distance from $z$ to $i-1$, while the absolute value of the denominator is the distance from $z$ to $1-i$.

Comment: Yes, the unit disk centered at the origin. $f(i-1)=0$.

Comment: yes, very obvious, I realised the instance I commented :) thanks a lot